# Html multilines tables (rowspan) - how to zebra the right way?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've got the following table, with the first line containing 2 sub-lines and the second one containing 3 sublines.

Whith this css style, the zebra color (**i.e. alternate color on two consecutive rows**) is faulty, second main cell shall be white, and not gray:

```
 tr:nth-child(odd)  {background-color: #eee;}
 tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #fff;}
```

[image: Faulty zebra with nth-child css]

So is there a way to zebra color such a table the right way?

Of course, my real problem deals with much more rows, with a much more variable number of sub-lines.

```
<head>
    <style>
        tr:nth-child(odd)  {background-color: #eee;}
        tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #fff;}
    </style>
<head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
                Big1
            </td>
            <td>
                small1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                small2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">
                Big2
            </td>
            <td>
                small1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                small2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                small3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: What is a "zebra color"?

Comment: Added a definition for zebra color: alternate color on two consecutive rows

Comment: What do you want the zebra stripes to look like?

Comment: On the included image, I want Big2 to be white, and not gray, as it's consecutive to a gray cell (Big1)

Comment: What you're seeing is the "right" way.  You have cells spanning multiple rows, so you'll have to assign specific colors to each cell.

Comment: Yeah, got it, in fact, Big2 and Small1 are on the same line, so I'll have to paint the cell one by one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as it is laid out.

It isnt working as

```
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            Big1
        </td>
        <td>
            small1
        </td>
    </tr>
```

will be grey, it's the first TR (odd)

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            small2
        </td>
    </tr>
```

will be white, its the second TR (even) etc.

Best way to do it will be to assign 'odd' and 'even' classes to the tr in question manually.

Comment: Indeed, I reached the same conclusion. Thanks, You've got the points